# Firestore - How to add next number while using Arrayunion?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm adding new number to an array each time  for current index, so what I want is that, I want to push next number for each time current index being added, if I have 0 current index then I want to add 1 with it and so on.

here is my code

```
 const indexRef = doc(db, `user/${uid}/${levelName}/${uid}/`);
      await updateDoc(indexRef, {
        CompletedIndex: arrayUnion(taskIndex),
        // add next number
       
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

tried this and it worked!

let me know if I do on wrong way

```
const indexRef = doc(db, `user/${uid}/${levelName}/${uid}/`);
      await updateDoc(indexRef, {
        CompletedIndex: arrayUnion(taskIndex),
      });
      await updateDoc(indexRef, {
        CompletedIndex: arrayUnion(taskIndex + 1),
      });
```